# how to convert Anonymous type to int

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I am using linq query in that i need all the values so first i am using linq query and

after that i am taking all values in one List like this

```
var lst = ProjectContext.My_prj_project.Select(i => new

             {
               Name = list                         

             }).Distinct().FirstOrDefault();                          

 ProjectReportDetailsModels l = new ProjectReportProjectCategoryDetailsModels();

 l.name= lst.Name;    // here i am getting error
```

connot implicitly convert 'AnonymousType#1' to 'int'

So please send me any sample, example (or) related link

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1):

This may help you

```
l.name = lst.Select(x=>x.Name);
```

Comment: This answer has already been given, and quite a few hours before you did. What do you feel this adds?

Answer (score 0):

you are getting a list in `lst` ? then why you are doing `FirstOrDefault()` ?

```
l.name = lst.Select(x=>x.Name).FirstOrDefault();
```

will solve the problem but i really cannot comprehend what you are doing ...